# TYPO3 9.5.7: Cannot unlock indexed_search indexing module for editors

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x, tx-indexed-search

I have a page with a file link content element. When I add a new (pdf) file or override an existing, the index data of this page is not updating. I have to delete the index data manually at the indexing module to get it work. I could live with that, if the editor of the webpage could use this module too. But I cannot unlock this module für my editors, because it's missing at the module list.

[image: Indexing] 
[image: Indexing module not listed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXT:indexed_search backend module is per default registered with admin access only.

You can change the current configuration for registered module in your custom site package extension in ext_tables.php for indexed_search module access for editors with following line:

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration']['web_IndexedSearchIsearch']['access'] = 'group,user';
```

Then you can unlock this module für your editors.

Comment: thanks, tried to add this to my ext_localconf.php, but the module is still missing. Is there something more to do, maybe replace something in your example or check some option at the usergroup?

Comment: I meant ext_tables.php - not ext_localconf.php. I did try this for first time, and it worked. Therefor i posted here :)

Comment: oops, I overread this, but I tried this at ext_tables.php too without success :(

Comment: ah okay, now it appears at the user group configuration, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ya, changes in ext_tables.php and ext_localconf.php requires cache being cleared. Good luck